# react native https request with .p12 or .pfx certificate best way

Tags: react-native, https, request, p12

I develop a mobile application with react native. When I try `HTTPS` request my service needs to client-side certificate authentication. I searched a lot of resources and I found these:

- https://github.com/localz/react-native-pinch
- https://github.com/approov/react-native-cert-pinner

I should be able to do this by writing a library by using client certificate authentication in native code and then using `NativeModules` to call it from javascript but it's really difficult.

Or maybe i need to add a middleware service.

Do you have any alternative solution to this problem? or what's the best practice?